Voice playback freezes while using SAPI TTS with delphi10
I'm trying to create a simple application to process received BLE data with Delphi10:
-Win10
-Delphi 11
-import SAPI from "onecore" directory(I only found Chinese language engine under this dir)
The code is simple:
unit unitTTS;

interface
uses
  SpeechLib_TLB,
  globalDefinitions,
  System.Generics.Collections, System.Generics.Defaults,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants;


type
  SPEAKFLAGS = (
    //--- SpVoice flags
    SPF_DEFAULT,
    SPF_ASYNC,
    SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK,
    SPF_IS_FILENAME,
    SPF_IS_XML,
    SPF_IS_NOT_XML,
    SPF_PERSIST_XML,

    //--- Normalizer flags
    SPF_NLP_SPEAK_PUNC,

    //--- TTS Format
    SPF_PARSE_SAPI,
    SPF_PARSE_SSML,
    SPF_PARSE_AUTODETECT,

    //--- Masks
    SPF_NLP_MASK,
    SPF_PARSE_MASK,
    SPF_VOICE_MASK,
    SPF_UNUSED_FLAGS
  );

  TextFlags=(
    TXTF_SCORE,
    TXTF_TIMEOUT,
    TXTF_OTHER
  );

  TmyTTS = class
    private
      FSpVoice:TSpVoice;

      function initCNSpeech(AOwner: TComponent):Boolean;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
      destructor Destroy;override;

      procedure speak(s:string;txtf:TextFlags);
      procedure SetRate(v:integer);
      procedure SetVolume(v:integer);
  end;

var
  tts : TmyTTS;

implementation


procedure TmyTTS.speak(s:string;txtf:TextFlags);
var
  flags:LongWord;
  cb:LongWord;
  pStatus: SPVOICESTATUS;
  ppszLastBookmark: PWideChar;
begin
  //exit;

  if FSpVoice = NIL then exit;
  if length(trim(s))=0 then exit;

  FSpVoice.GetStatus(pStatus,ppszLastBookmark);
  if pStatus.dwRunningState = 2 then
    case txtf of
      TXTF_SCORE:   FSpVoice.Speak('',2,cb);
      TXTF_TIMEOUT: exit;
      TXTF_OTHER:   exit;
    end;

  flags := LongWord(SPF_ASYNC);
  cb := 0;
  //不能使用@s，因为下标从1开始，0位置存储字符串长度，必须明确标出开始位置
  FSpVoice.Speak(@s[1],flags,cb);
end;


constructor TmyTTS.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create;
  initCNSpeech(AOwner);
end;

destructor TmyTTS.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNIL(FSpVoice);
  Inherited;
end;

procedure TmyTTS.SetRate(v:integer);
begin
  if FSpVoice = NIL then exit;
  FSpVoice.SetRate(v);
end;

procedure TmyTTS.SetVolume(v:integer);
begin
  if FSpVoice = NIL then exit;
  FSpVoice.SetVolume(v);
end;

function TmyTTS.initCNSpeech(AOwner: TComponent):Boolean;
var
  cnt:longword ;
  tok : ISpObjectToken;
  toks:IEnumSpObjectTokens;
  ppTokenCategory: ISpObjectTokenCategory;
begin
  Result := false;
  FSpVoice := TSpVoice.Create(AOwner);

  FSpVoice.GetVoice(&tok);
  tok.GetCategory(&ppTokenCategory);
  ppTokenCategory.EnumTokens('language=804',nil,&toks);
  toks.GetCount(cnt);
  if cnt=0 then
  begin
    showmessage('没有中文语音生成引擎.');
    FSpVoice.Free;
    exit;
  end;
  toks.Item(0,tok);
  FSpVoice.SetVoice(tok);

  result := true;
end;

end.


and it is simple to call:
tts.speak(s,TXTF_SCORE);
The problems I'm having are:

voice playback freezes,especially when OS with high load;
I think the root reason is the priority of application process,it was interrupted by other workload sometime.But we know other application can keep the voice playback smoothly,music plyer e.g. What is the right way to do it?
can't change speech rate;
it doesn't work : tts.SetRate(trunc(TTrackBar(Sender).Value));
But I can change it with OS GUI,and it reflects in playback.
I don't know if this is because of 'onecore' version.
Thanks for advices.

I have tried to launch the speack() in thread, it did not help.

I changed SPF_ASYNC to SPF_DEFAULT when calling speak(),the playback is good. Maybe the thread to execute speak() function can't get enough time to complete it's task in limited interval. But the user operation and the other task response getting very poor.

You are mixing APIs.  The TTS engines and voices in the onecore directory are designed to be called from the winrt::Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis APIs, not from SAPI.  I’m surprised it works at all, since the SR tokens are in the wrong place in the registry.

So,I need to re-import the ddl. What confused me is I can only find the language package under that directory,What 'onecore' means?

Eric Brown is right,I select the wrong API, after re-import the SAPI, I can change the rate now,and the interface is better than before.

The reason should be the priority set by asynchronous mode is too low.
I have created a non-stop thread with highest priority,it can finish the playback smoothly too(not so good as synchronous mode).
this is the code:
  TSpeechThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure delFirstString;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;
    
constructor TSpeechThread.Create;
begin
  Inherited Create(True);
  Priority:=tpTimeCritical;
  FreeOnTerminate:=false;
end;

procedure TSpeechThread.delFirstString;
begin
  if tts.FStrings.Count>0 then
    tts.FStrings.Delete(0);
end;

procedure TSpeechThread.Execute;
begin
  while(true) do
  if not Terminated  then
    begin
      if tts.FStrings<>NIL then
      begin
        if tts.FStrings.Count>0 then
          begin
            tts.speak(tts.FStrings[0],TXTF_SCORE);
            synchronize(delFirstString);
          end
        else
          suspend;
      end;
    end
  else
    break;
end;

cooperate code:
procedure TmyTTS.addSentence(s:string);
begin
  FStrings.Add(s);
  if (speechThread<>NIL) then
    if speechThread.Suspended then
      speechThread.Resume;
end;

But, I can't change the speech rate still.
Any advice is welcome.

Still freezes happened,though not so serious. What I posted is not the right solution. I noticed that there are many threads started after calling to speak() .They should share the time slice allocated to application(or OS will allocate time slice for every thread?)I don't know the workflow of TTS inner, maybe it playback on fly, for my case, we can create the audio first and then playback it one time. that way should be more smooth.

The playback is good if it runs as a seperate application regardless of what other applications are running.That means OS will allocate a time slice for the application,and all the threads of this application will share the allocated time slice. So, the simple solution is to build a seprate application which receives sentences and speaks them.

I did not find a way to solve the freeze problem in one application, as a way to by pass it, you can create a seperate application just play the sound,that is my way now. The reason is no necessary time resource for TTS thread in my current codes,maybe we can change the default way provided by the imported library,or find a way to keep TTS thread running in a high priority(in normal way,TTS thread priority could not be higher than it's process).
